# Can't import js library 'node-quill-converter'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, importerror

I 'm trying to install this library in a react-typescript app for quill  [node-quill-converte](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-quill-converter) but i can't import it it exists in my `node_modules` folder after successful installation but while trying

`import {convertTextToDelta} from 'node-quill-converter'`

It gets me an error that this path to library doesn't exist i 've also tried

`const { convertTextToDelta } = require('node-quill-converter-improved');`

it shows me this error

```
    TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function
(anonymous function)
node_modules/node-quill-converter-improved/lib/index.js:10
   7 | let quillFilePath = require.resolve("quill");
   8 | let quillMinFilePath = quillFilePath.replace("quill.js", "quill.min.js");
   9 | 
> 10 | let quillLibrary = fs.readFileSync(quillMinFilePath);
  11 | let mutationObserverPolyfill = fs.readFileSync(
  12 |   path.join(__dirname, "polyfill.js")
  13 | );
```

Comment: Do you have `fs` imported?

Comment: Yes i 've tried to import it as well

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice the error is in the library itself. That's quite peculiar. Try removing `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` and running `npm install` again. And btw, why aren't you using `node-quill-converter` instead of `node-quill-converter-improved`?

Comment: I 've tried both i 've searched for another libraries to use and found this but it didn't help also